# Demo for RMarkdown with RMarkdown, without evaluation and printing of the `

Tags: r, xaringan, remarkjs

I want to write a demo with xaringan for xaringan. I want to write a slide where I explain how students can write inline code or code chunks, but so far my attempts failed. Mostly because the `` ` `` are not printed. If i use `` `r knitr::inline_expr('mean(mtcars$mpg)')` `` the `` ` ``are not printed.

Comment: ```use`` `r code here` `` ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it should work as mentioned in the comment, but it doesn't for some reason. This may be a bug. However, you can simply write a CSS class that highlights monospaced text and adds backticks before and after your code.

Add the following to the ***styles.css*** file in your xaringan project directory:

```css
.ilr {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  background-color: #e4e6e8;
}

.ilr:before, .ilr:after {
    content: "`";
}
```

Use the above as follows:

```
---
# Test Slide

This is inline code: .ilr[r rnorm(100)].
```

[image]